# How to avoid read before write for updates in google datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = datastore.newKeyFactory().setKind("keyKind");
Key key = keyFactory.newKey("keyName");
Entity entity = datastore.get(key);
if (entity != null) {
  System.out.println("Updating access_time for " + entity.getString("name"));
  entity = Entity.newBuilder(entity)
      .set("access_time", DateTime.now())
      .build();
  datastore.update(entity);
}
```

https://github.com/googleapis/java-datastore#updating-data , as per this there has to be **a read before write**.
Can an update happen without read in google datastore? As in certain cases, I would not care if certain attributes are overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to know if an entity exists and can overwrite the data, then consider using [`upsert`](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#datastore-datastore-basic-entity-java)

Comment: `upsert` works like **create-or-update**, however, is there any way to update certain fields only (subsets of attributes) without reading the whole document, there by preserving other fields. As one would do in Cassandra?

Comment: No, Datastore is a document database and not a wide column store like Cassandra.  To update specific fields you need to read-modify-write the entity entity.  If you are worried about missed conflicts then the updates should be done in a transaction (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions).